# Mac .local domain-name stopped resolving

Tags: bonjour

My laptop had the hostname `Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local`, and I could ping it with `ping Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local`.

Today, it just stopped.  I can access co-workers' laptops with  `ping Name-MacBook-Pro.local`, with their names, but mine, I (and everybody else in the office) just gets `ping: cannot resolve Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local: Unknown host`

Bizarrely, this happened about an hour after I successfully upgraded the OS to Sierra.  It worked for a while, then stopped.

If someone could even give me a pointer to documentation of how it is *supposed* to work, I would be grateful.

Comment: Bonjour service discovery is a hack at best, and completely unreliable at worst (as you've seen). If you need to be able to reliably contact co-workers' systems using a hostname (but why??!?), then assign them DHCP reservations and a proper DNS name.

Comment: Here you have [a pointer to documentation of how it is *supposed* to work](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002458-SW1) (notice the "caching" paragraph). That's not really a question, but a request for learning material with a story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Sierra, your computer won't register a `.local` version of its name unless you start one of the Sharing services (like File Sharing, for instance).

I'm not sure why it happens and if there is a better way of circumventing that, but enable File Sharing (or any other Sharing service) will make an entry for `Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local` in DNS Service Discovery (you can check that via: `dns-sd -G v4 Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local`, and compare it with the non=local version: `dns-sd -G v4 Michaels-MacBook-Pro`).

Comment: Turning File Sharing on, _and then back off_ worked too.  **Edit:** may have spoken too soon.  It seemed to stop working after a minute or so.

Comment: There is a Time-to-Live of 120 seconds on the mDNS record created, so it might seem that the setup works immediately after deactivation of the sharing. And it does, for 120 seconds. :)

Comment: Using High Sierra, and my .local is being broadcast without any file sharing or other sharing enabled.

Comment: After passing from High Sierra to Mojave I also started having this problem (I have Mojave 10.14.4). The workaround of turning on a sharing service worked for me. Interestingly, I discovered the issue because I am working on a Java software that uses JDI: I discovered that JDI uses (ouch!) the local network name to open sockets and communicate with a Java process to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing tnarik's suggestion to turn on a sharing service, which was a necessary step that helped me a lot on Sierra, v10.12.6:

I also had to uncheck "Enable stealth mode" in my firewall preferences to receive a ping reply via .local.

The checkbox is at "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "Firewall" -> "Firewall Options..." -> "Enable stealth mode" [with description "Don't respond to or acknowledge attempts to access this computer from the network by test applications using ICMP, such as Ping"]

Answer (score -1):

If it really means to you, you can always assign it in your hosts file.

```
YOURLOCALIP Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Do this on your and others PC you want to access domain from.
More info can be found here:

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks, but not a solution for me: I move the laptop to different networks, where it gets different IP addresses.

Comment: Add 127.0.0.1 instead of yourlocalip it actually may help without need to create on other pc.

Answer (score -1):

Please start iTunes.app on your Mac and reload `Michaels-MacBook-Pro.local` in your browser.

Comment: Nothing happened.  Was something supposed to happen?